# Why does char == 'L' and char != 'L' have the same output?

Tags: java

What I want to happen: I want to save the current value to a char holder variable. So that, if the current value != holder value it should print move left but when the current value is equal to holder value it should move forward.

Problem: The char value holder outputs the same with other statements.
What suppose to be the problem?

Just based on the direction when it loops.

```
public void reconstructPath(Node node) {
    while (node.parent != null) {
        //DIRECTIONS: L - Left, R - Right, U - up, D - Down
        int nextX, nextY;
        char direction = 0; 
        char current = 0;
        nextX = node.parent.x;
        nextY = node.parent.y;

        if(nextX == node.x)
        {   

            if(nextY > node.y){
                direction = 'D';
            }   
            else{
                direction = 'U';


            }

        }else if(nextY == node.y){  

            if(nextX > node.x){             
                direction = 'R';

            }else{
                direction = 'L';
                if(direction != 'L'){
                    System.out.println("move forward");
                }else{
                    char holder = direction;
                    System.out.println("move up");
                }

            }
        }

        System.out.printf("Traceback: (%d, %d) go %c\n", node.x, node.y, direction);
        node = node.parent;

    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
move L // first L should be left.
Traceback: (4, 1) go L
move L // this should move forward instead of left.
Traceback: (3, 1) go L
move L
Traceback: (2, 1) go L
```

Comment: Why would you do this? `direction = 'L'; if(direction != 'L')` You're forcing it to `L` and then immediately checking it?

Comment: It would be helpful to see where `direction` is declared. If it is declared as a `String` that could explain the behavior.

Comment: Using a debugger with breakpoints would help you see that you `direction` is always equal to `'L'` when you compare `direction` to `'L'`.

Comment: I have added where the direction is declared. What i want is when if its the first 'L' it should move left. But if 'L' again i should move forward. i'm using something to hold the prev char direction value and compare it with the new one if its the same value or not. But my expected output is not getting the correct output

Comment: 1. Discover the IDE. 2. Discover automatic code formatting. 3. Never let this kind of mistake slip by again.

Comment: okay thanks for understanding mi Marko

Comment: No reason to take offence---I really mean it. IDE is here to help you avoid  a huge number of typical coding mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

consider these two consecutive lines:

```
    direction = 'L';
    if(direction != 'L')
```

Are you missing a close brace after the first one?

Comment: No I'm not missing any braces.

Comment: If you're not missing any braces, then please rewrite the code to `direction = 'L'; System.out.println("move up");`---because that is the exact equivalent of the code you have now, only with dead code removed.

Comment: YES, you are missing a brace -- or to be more accurate -- your brace is in the wrong place.   The code I quoted is "nonsense".  It is syntactically correct but it doesn't mean anything useful.   As Marko pointed out the if condition will always be false because the assignment just set the value you are testing.   Put in a brace, remove the unnecessary brace down below and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

When you find "L", you have to check if previous value was "L" or not.

To implement this solution, you have to remember your old value:

```
public void reconstructPath(Node node) {
    char lastDirection = (char)-1;
    while (node.parent != null) {
        //DIRECTIONS: L - Left, R - Right, U - up, D - Down
        int nextX, nextY;
        char direction = 0; 
        char current = 0;
        nextX = node.parent.x;
        nextY = node.parent.y;

        if(nextX == node.x)
        {   

            if(nextY > node.y){
                direction = 'D';
            }   
            else{
                direction = 'U';


            }

        }else if(nextY == node.y){  

            if(nextX > node.x){             
                direction = 'R';

            }else{
                direction = 'L';
                if(lastDirection == 'L'){
                    System.out.println("move forward");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("move up");
                }

            }
        }
       lastDirection = direction;
        System.out.printf("Traceback: (%d, %d) go %c\n", node.x, node.y, direction);
        node = node.parent;

    }

}
```

Comment: still same output. first L move up. 2nd L move UP. 2nd L should be move forward

Comment: quiblle:  this is not a declaration, it is an assignment.  Please use technical terms accurately.

Comment: You have to remember your old value

Comment: Error: lastDirection be resolved to a variable. @MatteoRubini